# Filter all traffic trough a gateway seamlessly

Tags: networking, router, routing, iptables, netfilter

I would like to filter the whole traffic to and from my computer. For that, I've developped a small piece of `python` code that uses `NetFilterQueue` (`NFQueue`), intercepts the packets and chooses if it must be dropped or not. Pretty basic so.

I'd like to run this code on a NanoPi R2S which is a Linux device with 2 ethernet ports on it. One port will be plugged to my home router while the second will be connected to my computer. I don't want to change the IP of my computer as it needs to be reachable from another device on my network.

```
┌──────────────┐    ┌───────────────┐    ┌───────────────┐
│              │    │               │    │               │
│  Home router │◄──►│  2 ethernets  │◄──►│  My computer  │
│              │eth0│    Gateway    │eth1│               │
└──────────────┘    └───────────────┘    └───────────────┘
```

What I'd like to do is to add the required `iptables` rules to filter all packets.

I've applied these rules but I'm not sure they are right. The plan is to seamlessly forward all the packets as if the gateway was not present.

```bash
    # Enable IP forwarding
    echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
    echo '1' > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding

    # Add iptables rules
    iptables -F # Delete all previous rules
    iptables -X # Delete user-defined chains
    iptables -F -t nat # Flush NAT table
    iptables -X -t nat # Delete user-defined chains in NAT table
    iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT # Allow loopback traffic
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT # Allow loopback traffic
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 # Direct traffic to gateway device
    iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 # Direct traffic to gateway device
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 # Direct traffic from gateway device
    iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 # Direct traffic from gateway device
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 # Traffic from left to right through gateway
    iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1 #Traffic from right to left through gateway
    ip6tables -P INPUT DROP # Disallow all IPv6 traffic
    ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP # Disallow all IPv6 traffic
    ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP # Disallow all IPv6 traffic
    iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4 # Auto-reload on reboot
    ip6tables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v6 # Auto-reload on reboot
```

I'm not sure if I need to set a new route to the home router. Maybe something like that:

```bash
ip route add default via <router_ip> dev eth0
```

Could you let me know if this behaviour is possible and if those rules are enought to filter my whole traffic ?